# Executing DTSX file (SSIS package) remotely and capturing events

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I'm going through a simple app we have and am trying to make some changes/improve it. Currently, we have the app running a bat file on the remote computer which in turn executes the DTSX file. That works fine.

What I'd like to be able to do is capture the events/output from the bat/dtsx file. I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx), but since I'm not running the DTSX file directly through code I'm not sure if that applies here. I know very little about running DTSX/SSIS packages, so I'm not really even sure where to begin here.

Should also note that this is being done in VB.NET.

Comment: Are you talking about DTS (legacy) or DTSX aka SSIS packages?

Comment: Sorry, it's DTSX (SSIS packages).

Comment: So you have a batch script with something like `dtexec.exe /file myPackage.dtsx ...` being started from VB.NET and the desire is to capture the information that the running package spits out? Text file good enough?

Comment: Yes. The VB.NET executes the remote batch script (which has dtexec.exe /file myPackage.dtsx). It's already being displayed/output to the command prompt window on the computer running the VB.NET app, but I don't really know if I can/should parse that, if I need to put it into a text file first, or if there's an already existing method to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the most simple option would be to modify the batch script to redirect the output.

```
dtexec.exe /file myPackage.dtsx > myPackage.log
```

This will overwrite the log file per execution. You can get fancier by appending the current %date% and %time% to the output file name.

The next option could be to change your invocation code. Instead of redirecting the batch script to write to a file, you can have the .NET code read in what's being displayed. Not the greatest code and it's in C# but I need to get to a meeting and don't have time to change it out. The following code looks at the ProcessResults object and pulls out the standard out and standard error streams.

```
            this.processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(this.dtUtilPath, parameters);
            this.processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            this.processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            this.processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            this.processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = null;

            // Perhaps it would be better to set this to 0 so that it runs to completion
            int waitInMilliSeconds = 1 * 1000;

            process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(this.processStartInfo);
            System.IO.StreamReader standardError = process.StandardError;
            System.IO.StreamReader standardOutput = process.StandardOutput;
            process.WaitForExit(waitInMilliSeconds);
            if (process.HasExited)
            {
                // Did it do well?
                // Currently, prints results to console but based on
                // exit code values can do whatever the business need is
                System.Console.WriteLine(standardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                System.Console.WriteLine(standardError.ReadToEnd());
                System.Console.WriteLine(process.ExitCode);
            }
```

At this point though, with either of the above solutions you are looking at parsing the above text for "whatever information you deem important." If it were me and based on what little I know so far of the problem domain, I'd skip the .NET capturing of information entirely. The batch script capture might be helpful if you like double duty but I'd go for native [SSIS logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246.aspx). This will require a code change on your deployed packages but I find I have the best SSIS experience by

1. turning on logging,
2. capturing OnError, OnTaskFailed, OnInformation, OnWarning and OnPre/PostExecute events
3. logging to SQL Server (2005 will log to dbo.sysdtslog90, 2008, R2 and 2012 in package deployment mode log to dbo.sysssislog. These tables exist in msdb but if the supplied connection string is pointing to a different catalog, the table will be created in that catalog and logging will occur there)

Comment: The only thing here that has confused me is the ProcessResults() object. That object doesn't seem to exist. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hah, yes you are umm missing that I didn't look far enough through my sample code. I had defined that structure internally to that project. Let me clean up the above code

Comment: Thanks. It'll take me a while to get the entire app completed, but it looks like this should work (or at least I can make it work).